# Crystal Reports Dynamic Cascading parameters are not populating

Tags: crystal-reports

**System:**

Windows 7 with Crystal Reports 2013 Demo. 
Windows 7 with Crystal Reports 11.5.12.1838

Initially Dynamic cascading parameters were not working for existing reports written by other analysts. The analysts are using XP systems. When they open the reports, their prompts populate correctly. Mine are blank. We downloaded 2013 to see if it was fixed in this version since XI is so old and is not officially supported on Windows 7. For one day the reports dynamic prompts were populating correctly and we were all excited. I continued on modifying the report, but had an issue and the application got closed non-gracefully. Now no dynamic prompts are populating in the report that was working yesterday. And again, any report that I open with dynamic cascading prompts do not populate. This has been an ongoing issue that we were excited that a resolution had appeared, but now we are back to square one. One of the other analysts was able to open the report again in XI and see the prompts correctly. This is a standalone report. We do not have a Crystal Report Server. We do not have Business View Manager. This issue is occuring in the designer for crystal reports on my computer only. When i copy the report to our test server and use our third party viewer(datalink) the prompts work fine.

**Furthermore:** Originally because of non-administrative privileges, I had my ODBC Drivers setup in user DSN. With the help of an Admin user, i setup the drivers in System DSN. I reloaded the original production report that I was trying to modify and set the location to my new dev odbc connections. But that still did not load the dynamic parameters.

**From Crystal Reports Designer**
[image: From Crystal Designer]

**From Datalink Viewer**
[image: From Datalink Viewer]

Any suggestions on how to troubleshoot this?

Comment: This sounds like a CR runtime issue to me. You said after installing CR 13 it worked until your system crashed? I would try reinstalling (maybe uninstall first) CR 13 and then reboot.

Comment: removal and reinstallation did not work. I have also tried swapping around different odbc drivers. And I have tried recreating the cascading parameters in a new report, only using the tables needed to create the cascade. That did not work either.

Comment: So when you create a parameter and you try to add values to it (either from table or manually), no values show when you run the report in CR? Are you getting any data at all?

Comment: campagnolo_1 the issue is that the dynamic parameters are not filling with data on my computer. At one time they were, now they are not. Running the report in our viewer software prompts for the parameters correctly, even when using my non-prompting report.

Comment: The fact that DataLink will show the reports still leads me to believe that the runtime versions somehow are not right. Which version of DataLink are you running?

Comment: @campagnolo_1 ok, I think you are on to something. :) I tried running the same report using datalink viewer 11 that is installed on my pc, and the same thing happens. The viewers that work are installed on a citrix cluster and have been in use for a while. So. What do I have to do to fix the runtimes? I have alread uninstalled and reinstalled CR2013.

Comment: CHeck this article out: http://search.sap.com/notes?id=0001786406&boj=/sap/bc/bsp/spn/scn_bosap/notes.do?access=69765F6D6F64653D3939382669765F7361706E6F7465735F6E756D6265723D30303031373836343036 I would also search the SAP forums some more. I'm honestly not sure which runtime you need, but they may be able to help more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK. This appears to be one solution. I was working with another laptop, that had a working crystal reports version. BUT, i had to do the whole maximumrowsets fix. Well, I must have messed up because the working crystal reports started doing the same thing. Oops. So I uninstalled crystal reports, deleted any of the registry keys associated with it, deleted any of the folder locations, rebooted and reinstalled and voila...it worked again. so then i used 
[this site](http://www.crystaladvice.com/crystalreports/fix-increase-number-of-parameter-values-lov) and it continued to work as desired. This probably isnt the only solution, but it definitely worked for me.

I'd also like to thank campagnolo-1 for his tireless assistance.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a connection issue. Is the new OS 64 bits ? If it is, you need to create the ODBC connection using the tool placed in this path: C:\Windows\SysWOW64\odbcad32.exe

Comment: yes, that is where the odbc connections are setup. Originally I had to do them as user settings. But in the troubleshooting and gaining temporary admin rights, i have them setup as system dsn now.

Comment: Are you sure you are using the tool from SysWOW64 folder ?

Comment: Lan, I believe if his data connector were wrong he would get a database connection error.